# Queue Resque Jobs from NodeJS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, redis, resque

I want to queue Resque jobs from NodeJS. Monitoring Redis commands I see:

```
1346127083.495055 "sadd" "resque:w:tasks:queues" "facebook"
1346127083.495471 "rpush" "resque:w:tasks:queue:facebook" "{\"class\":\"Hello::FacebookFriends\",\"args\":[\"2342324\"]}"
```

Issuing those commands directly from Node seems to work. Are there any hidden bugs or things I'm not aware of here?

**Update**: My jobs are written in Ruby. While I love NodeJS and I'm way better in Javascript, I need tons of libraries that are still not available in a great condition in NPM, for example communicating with Twitter and Facebook (Twitter and Koala gems, There's nothing comparable for Node). So I want to start Ruby Jobs from my NodeJS service.

So far I'm using something that looks similar to this function from coffee-resque:

```
 enqueue: (queue, func, args) ->
    @redis.sadd  @key('queues'), queue
    @redis.rpush @key('queue', queue),
      JSON.stringify class: func, args: args || []
```

Here:

```
job = JSON.stringify
    class: 'Hello::FacebookFriends'
    args: [user_id, fb.id]
@redis_client.multi()
    .sadd('resque:w:tasks:queues', 'facebook')
    .rpush('resque:w:tasks:queue:facebook', job)
    .exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set up a service that fires off the jobs? It would be an extra hop through the network, but the code should be simple enough(look at http://www.sinatrarb.com/ for example).

Comment: What do you mean? Creating a route in ruby then pinging it from Node?

Comment: Precisely, create a route that, when called, creates the job. It's not a pretty solution, but it should do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use: https://github.com/technoweenie/coffee-resque

(the name says coffee but you can use it with javascript too)
Looks pretty simple too, and you'll be a bit safer against unexpected results, breaking changes, etc.

Comment: Oh wow, I was sure it's an actual PORT of Resque (like their docs says). Thank you.

Comment: It is a PORT! I just had to look inside the source code to realize I was double wrong. Also, it doesn't seem, and I might be wrong here, to actually spawn separate threads for the workers. What.

Comment: Well, I suppose you wanted to enqueue jobs from Node.js. And coffee-resque does just that.
If you just want to enqueue, why do you care about workers?
Apparently the enqueue function in coffee-resque is trivial, so you can just copy it. I just was pointing out that by using it you're safe that if a change in resque format is done, a coffee-resque update will handle that for you.

Comment: From the source code, and I didn't look too carefully, Coffee-Resque creates workers inside the server thread, that's the complete opposite of what workers should do. So just enqueuing stuff on Redis is good enough? Resque will take care of the cleanup?

Comment: If you just want to enqueue jobs, I'm sure coffee-resque won't create any worker (or that would be very bad bug on it).
And cleanup is more likely to be done by resque workers yes.
Although so far, if the source looks like enqueueing is that simple, it doesnt sound bad to just copy that code, and avoid adding another dependency, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use node-resque from TaskRabbit

**Lambda code**

```js
const NodeResque = require('node-resque')
const connectionDetails = {
  pkg: 'ioredis',
  host: 'redis host',
  port: 6379
}
const queue = new NodeResque.Queue({
  connection: connectionDetails
})
queue.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error)
})
await queue.connect()
await queue.enqueue('queue_name', 'WorkerClassName', ['arg1', 'arg2', ..])
await queue.end()
```

**Rails worker code to process the task**

```ruby
class WorkerClassName
    @queue = :queue_name
    def self.perform(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        # Logic
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [node-resque](https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque) library by TaskRabbit to do this.

Here is an [an article](https://scalegrid.io/blog/visualizing-resque-usage-using-node-js-websockets-and-redis/) that might help you get started. It also has a link to a demo hosted on Heroku where you may connect your Redis instance and see your Resque queues and jobs.